# Why does a TidTCPClient in a separate thread block the main thread?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, indy10

A separate thread creates a TidTCPClient and a TTimer. The TTimer is set to 3s and if the TCPClient is not connected, it calls TCPClient.Connect.
If there is no server to connect to, this results in an attempt to connect every 3 seconds.

The main thread (UI) does nothing, but if I grab the window with the mouse and move it slowly across the screen, it get's stuck every 3 seconds for about 2 seconds, then it jumps to the mouse-cursor position and follows the mouse again, until the next attempt to connect occurs.

In other words, the main thread seems to be blocked when the TCPClient tries to connect.

Why does this happen, even though the TCPClient is in it's separate thread?

Comment: Components don't exist in threads, they exist in memory.  Code executes in the thread you call it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your TTimer works by receiving WM_TIMER messages; Those messages are dispatched using the VCL's main message pump, in the VCL threads. After the 3 seconds expire your TTimer.OnTimer event runs *in the main thread*, so the call to `Connect` runs in the main VCL thread.

You get blocked because you're not threading!

Comment: This is only true if the `TTimer` is created in the main thread context, such as in the thread's constructor. In order to have a TTimer run inside a thread, it needs to be created inside the thread's `Execute()` method instead, and then the thread needs its own message loop so the `WM_TIMER` messages are dispatched correctly. Even then, `TTimer` is not thread-safe (because of its use of `AllocateHWnd()` internally), so you should use `SetTimer()` directly, or even a waitable timer via `CreateWaitableTimer()`, a multimedia timer via `timeSetEvent()`, or even just a manual sleep loop.

Comment: Yes, the timer was created in the Thread's constructor. Thanks for the explanations